How to Customize Indigo Theme and CSS Variables for Micro-Frontends in Open edX?
I’m working with Open edX, specifically using the Indigo theme and Micro-Frontends (MFEs). I want to customize the theme by setting CSS variables or tokens to maintain consistent branding across the platform. However, I’ve run into some challenges and am not sure how to proceed.
My Setup:

Open edX platform is hosted with the Indigo theme.
I’m working with Tutor for managing the Open edX instance.
The Micro-Frontends (React-based) are running on apps.local.edly.io.

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve looked into modifying the Indigo theme’s Sass variables (e.g.,
$primary-color) but couldn’t figure out the process to make these
changes take effect.
I don’t have React components inside the indigo-theme folder to
directly manage styles or tokens for MFEs.
I’ve come across mentions of the edx/brand package, but I’m unclear
on how to use it to integrate the custom styles with MFEs.

Questions:

How can I customize the Indigo theme to define CSS variables or
tokens?
Is it possible to ensure these customizations are applied across both
the core platform and the MFEs? If yes, what’s the best way to do
this?
Do I need to modify or replace the edx/brand package for this, and
how do I integrate it properly with Tutor-managed MFEs?

I’d appreciate detailed instructions or pointers to documentation that can help me resolve this issue. Let me know if more details about my setup are needed. Thanks!
